# Linear system 2 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

There are $x$ white and $y$ black pearls and their ratio is $z$. If I add six black and six white pearles, the ratio doubles.

I did the following:

$ \frac{x+6}{y+6} = \frac{2x}{y}$ and then I get 
$xy -6(2x-y)=0$

I can find solutions by guessing. Is there any other way?

ADDED:

Now I have to solve the problem for
$ \frac{c(x+y)+6}{x+y+12} = 2c $ and once again I am lost in factoring out variables.

Comment: You actually have two equations, the ones you wrote already.$z$ should not be considered as an unknown, but rather as a constant-a parameter that gives different problems. Solve $x,y$ for $z$ and you have your solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the question! Is there any way to get solutions or I can only find by guessi them?

Comment: There are infinetely many solutions because for every value of, say $x$, you plug in, you find a certain $y$ (which is a $y(x)$) that corresponds to that, while simultaneously satisfying your equations. That is, you have a "family" of problems, each one different from the others in respect to the ratio $z$ (a different $z$ gives a different problem), but all off them with a similar form of solutions, in that the given ratio is always maintained. I hope this makes it clearer!

Comment: @MathematicianBymistake $x,y$ are integers. Thus there are finite solutions.

Comment: @MXYMXY You are correct! I failed to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x}{y} = z$ and $\frac{x+6}{y+6} = 2z$

$\implies x = zy$ and $\frac{zy+6}{y+6} = 2z$

$\implies 6 = z(y+12) \implies z = \frac{6}{y+12}$

$\implies x = zy = \frac{6y}{y+12}$

Since $x$ and $y$ are the number of pearls, they must be integers. That is

$(y+12) | (6y)$.

There are only 3 possible $y$ values by giving $x=2, x=3, x=4$. Other $x$ values gives non-integer or non-positive $y$'s.

Thus, all possible $(x,y)$ pairs are $(2,6), (3,12), (4,24)$